# Find first row of a matrix <= to a vector

Tags: matrix, vector, julia

I have a two arrays `t1::Array{Float64, 2}` and `t2::Array{Float64, 2}` with the same number of columns. `t2` only has one line.

I want to find the first row of `t1` which is `<= t2` (i.e., the first row `i` such that `t1[i, j] <= t2[1, j]` for all `j`). In the previous version of julia I was using this command:

```
findfirst(all(t1 .<= t2, 2))
```

It does not work anymore. The command `all(t1 .<= t2, 2)` returns the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type BitArray{2} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
```

Could you tell me how to do it in a more recent version of julia without using for loops? (I am using 1.1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `all` is now `all(A; dims)`, so you can use `all(x .<= y; dims=2)` instead:

```
julia> x = [4 5 6]
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5  6

julia> y = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3
  4   5   6
  7   8   9
 10  11  12

julia> all(x .<= y; dims=2)
4×1 BitArray{2}:
 0
 1
 1
 1
```

However, note that the output of `all(x .<= y; dims=2)` is a column matrix (*not* a vector), so if you apply `findfirst` to it, then `findfirst` returns a `CartesianIndex`:

```
julia> findfirst(all(x .<= y; dims=2))
CartesianIndex(2, 1)
```

If you want an integer with the row number, you can simply extract the first element of the `CartesianIndex`:

```
julia> findfirst(all(x .<= y; dims=2))[1]
2
```

Alternatively, you could turn the output of `all` into a vector using `vec`:

```
julia> findfirst(vec(all(x .<= y; dims=2)))
2
```

Comment: Or `dropdims(all(x .<= y; dims=2), dims=2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the closest equivalent

```
julia> x = [4 5 6]
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5  6

julia> y = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3
  4   5   6
  7   8   9
 10  11  12

julia> findfirst(all, collect(eachrow(x .<= y)))
2
```